# Transforming shapefile into raster file in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, shapefile, convert

I'd like to transform a shapefile into raster file in QGIS and the opposite way back also (raster to shapefile).

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

For Shapefile to raster see [How to convert a vector layer to raster?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22704/how-to-convert-a-vector-layer-to-raster).

You're looking for **"Rasterize" and "Polygonize"** tools in Raster menu (gdal plugin).