# how to make grid cells by point data

Tags: raster, csv

I have a csv data. the X, and Y columns show bottom left corner of each grid. It is supposed to show as grid square, but it shows points. what is the problem? and is there any way I can make cell grids from these points?

Comment: What software are you using? What have you tried? What do you mean by "grid cells"--a raster or a vector layer of polygons? In what sense are these data "supposed" to display as squares: what's your documentation for that?

Answer (score 3):

from your question I am assuming that you want to create a raster grid. There are several ways to do this with a spreadsheet, I recommend using QGIS, convert the spreadsheet to a point shapefile: http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/importing_spreadsheets_csv.html 
To convert the points to raster use the QGIS "convert vector to raster" too mentioned here: [How to convert a vector layer to raster?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22704/how-to-convert-a-vector-layer-to-raster) or if you you could consider interpolating the values using the "interpolate" tool