# Making DEM raster file using centroid point shapefile in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, saga

I had a DEM file at first. Then I converted it to centroid points vector to add some data to it. So, I ended up with a vector with millions of points. Now I added my data and I want to use "elevation" attribute to again make a raster out of my points.

My elevation attributes column range is from 0.0000 to 22.3200 but waterer method I have so far tried gave me a raster layer with an irrelevant range e.g.. 8.500 to 10.500.

Comment: What is the additional information you're adding? as converting back to raster will just lose any additional information you add to the centroids, Unless that's the field you are using for the raster cell value.  How have you got your min/max cell values? from statistics or just the range the raster loads up with.  Have changed the style properties from 'cumulative count cut' to 'min/max'?

Answer (score 1):

You could interpolate them back onto a grid, using the 'raster' -> 'analysis' -> 'grid (interpolation)' tool.

[image]

Or you can use the vector tool 'rasterize'. See here: [Convert vector data with irregular points (no grid) to raster with QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72615/convert-vector-data-with-irregular-points-no-grid-to-raster-with-qgis)