# Visualizing geo count data points in gradual colors using ArcGIS desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, csv, visualisation

[image]

I have data looking like the following:

```
Latitude  Longitude  Class
35.773444  -78.6305752  0
38.82349688  -77.61919194  1
41.4985021  -81.7144364  1
39.9528  -75.2104  0
```

Longitude, latitude and classification columns. Attached is the simple map I have created in ArcGIS. But ultimately how I imagine to display the map includes the followings:

*** 1) States with more dots (red or green) will be enlarged in size comparing to States with less or no dots

*** 2) States with more green dots become more green, States with more red dots become more red

I have seen examples where the colors of each states are gradually different (for example: population size for each state), but the actual numbers (ie: State populations) are already recorded in the data file. As you can see in my original data file, it only has lat and lon data, I don't have numbers of dots per State in my data.

Comment: You can't change the size of the state polygons based on the number of points. Well you can, but that's called a cartogram and takes special scripting or tools. To make the states different colors or shades, you'd need to do a spatial join with a count method to figure out how many of each point were in each state. And likely twice, once for red and once for green. Then you'd need to create a [bivariate map](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/104093/), since states have both red and green. I don't really understand your data (you've got x,y and 'class') so I can't suggest anything else.

Comment: I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  I recommend taking the 2-minute [Tour] that is designed to introduce all users to our focussed Q&A format.