# Create raster from cadastre (property lot data) polygon

Tags: qgis, raster, polygon, kml

I have a cadastre (property lots) polygon dataset of a region.

Have used rule-base style in QGIS to show different groups of properties in the dataset classified based on their property lot size (ie. all properties 0 - 400sqm size, 401 - 800sqm size... etc).

Want to create a raster of this (ie. showing the different groups eg. 0 - 400sqm, 401 - 800sqm...) and then save as this as a kml for viewing in Google earth.

Obviously the polygon dataset is just too huge to view in Google earth, further only interested in the classified image output rather than any vectorised data.

Comment: Have a read of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22704/how-to-convert-a-vector-layer-to-raster and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I would have thought you could convey more detail by keeping the data in a vector format. Regardless, QGIS now has an option or a plugin to export a referenced raster direct from the map canvas view. So you need only make the map (sounds like you have done that) and use the plugin.

You need to enable experimental plugins and install GeorefExport.

Once installed you will have to find the toolbar icon to activate the plugin, it doesn't seem to be available from the menus. 
Unfortunately there seems to be limited documentation.
https://github.com/valruggero/georefexport

ciao