# Determination of Soil Moisture for a Region Using open Source Data

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, landsat, sentinel-1

I want to derive soil Moisture for a region using Landsat and Microwave data could you please help me with the procedure.

Comment: This needs clarification. Do you have the data already? What format? Are you looking for the data? Do you know how to calculate it if you did have the data and just want to figure it out in QGIS? Have you done the basic research on this?

Comment: I have Landsat 8 data and Sentinel which i need to download. SMAP provides direct result but its not available free of cost now. I just Got a way to get LST and NDVI and using which i can generate Soil Moisture Index. Further research is being Processed.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to get at this.

- [ESRI](http://www.esri.com/landing-pages/software/landsat/unlock-earths-secrets) and [ArcGIS Online](http://www.arcgis.com/features/)
- Raw Landsat Data

First take a read of my comments on [Converting satellite image into raster](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/160575/25060). There it explains how you can [Mapbox Landsat Live](https://www.mapbox.com/bites/00145/#7/15.014/34.398) to begin to harvest your own [Landsat Data using AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/public-data-sets/landsat/).

---

### ESRI and ArcGIS Online

You can access and display soil moisture using data using ArcGIS's pipeline to Landsat Imagery.

1. Copy the `http://landsat2.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/Landsat/MS/ImageServer`data location.
2. Using [ArcGIS Online](http://www.arcgis.com/features/) create a new map and add the data location from Step 1 into the map using the Add Data button. Select Add Layer From Web. [image: Add Layer From Web]
3. Paste Link from Step 1 into dialogue box that pops up
4. Select the More Options function (three blue dots at end of the layer)
5. Select Image Display
   [image]
6. Select Normalized Difference Moisture Index Colorized[image]
7. Click Apply. Click Close.
8. MAKE SURE TO DO THIS!!! - Go to More Options Again. Click Disable Time Animation. If you do not do this you will just get a giant brown blob of the world. [image]

---

### Raw Landsat Data

To get the Raw Landsat data you will need to understand which [Bands](https://www.mapbox.com/blog/putting-landsat-8-bands-to-work/) you will require. Hint (you will want [band 5, 6, or 7](http://landsat.usgs.gov/best_spectral_bands_to_use.php) depending on your need)

1. Go find out where in the world you will be looking for data using [Landsat Live](https://www.mapbox.com/bites/00145/#7/15.014/34.398)
2. Gather the #LC8 (e.g. #LC8172050215305LGN00) number from the Raw Imagery window pane. [image]
3. Gather the file number (e.g. #LC8172050215305LGN00) then go to [Landsat on AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/public-data-sets/landsat/) using the link format 
   `http://landsat-pds.s3.amazonaws.com/L8/172/050/LC81720502015305LGN00/index.html`​ Replace 015 with the Path and replace 033 with the Row. Then gather the title _B6 and _B7 from the [link](http://landsat-pds.s3.amazonaws.com/L8/015/033/LC80150332015229LGN00/index.html).
4. Hint. The link(http://landsat-pds.s3.amazonaws.com/L8/172/050/LC81720502015305LGN00/index.html) structure is cut up from the input of the original #LC8 from step 2. L8/172/050/...(see Path/Row in Landsat Live Image from Step 2)
5. Take the imagery into your desired software and manipulate the bands as you see fit.