# Python: Write Grid to TIFF

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff

I have a grid I am trying to write out as GeoTIFF with a resolution of 250. I have tried a few options like using rasterio but not successful, any ideas how to write it out successfully using python?

```
area_grid [7866 rows x 3 columns] attribute table looks like this:

                      geometry                      Grid_ID  Count
0     ((-2061272.927 869431.042, -2063772.92...        0      0
1     ((-2061272.927 878091.296, -2063772.92...        1      0
2     ((-2061272.927 886751.550, -2063772.92...        2      0
3     ((-2061272.927 895411.804, -2063772.92...        3      0
4     ((-2061272.927 904072.058, -2063772.92...        4      0
...                                                 ...      ...  
7861  ((-1498772.927 1722466.064, -1501272.9...     7861      0
7862  ((-1498772.927 1731126.318, -1501272.9...     7862      0
7863  ((-1498772.927 1739786.572, -1501272.9...     7863      0
7864  ((-1498772.927 1748446.826, -1501272.9...     7864      0
7865  ((-1498772.927 1757107.081, -1501272.9...     7865      0
```

Comment: I don't know if it would work for your purposes, but one easy thing to try is to just rasterize your polygons a la https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22704/converting-vector-layer-to-raster-using-qgis. It might be tricky to get a 1:1 polygon:pixel relationship with this method, though.